# Fix training and testing dataset for every run in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pytorch, dataset

I have created a `dataset` in `pytorch`. In the `training.py` file, I called the dataset by from `src.data import dataSetSource`. I checked the type of the datapoint stored in the dataset, it is `dict`.

Dataset size is `582 X 2 X 36 X 36`. I want to split my dataset in to a training and testing. In splitting the dataset, I want to use same test data everytime I run the model. Since i am working with pytorch, I dont really know how to save the training and testing dataset in a separate dataframe.

```
spherePixels = 36
# Loading the dataset
dataset = dataSetSource`(spherePixels,'data/{}')

train_size = round(0.8 * len(dataset))
val_size = round(0.1 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size - val_size 

train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])
```

I have written above code but it takes random and different value for training and testing everytime. I want to fix my training and testing dataset. How can I do this?

Comment: Just save the `*_dataset` using pickle?

Answer (score 0):

The doc of [`torch.utils.data.random_split()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) tells you how to do this:

> Optionally fix the generator for reproducible results, e.g.:
>
> > random_split(range(10), [3, 7], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))

Here is an example:

```
import torch

data = torch.arange(100)[:, None]  # dummy dataset, shape (100, 1)

train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [50, 50], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(1))
train.indices[:5]  # output [45, 15, 90, 32, 35]

train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [50, 50], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(1))
train.indices[:5]  # output [45, 15, 90, 32, 35]
```